# How can I stop Xcode from managing version control?

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

Xcode is showing me an older version of my project. A version way behind the remote repo. What makes it more strange to me is if I go in my project folder all the files are as they should be. How can I get Xcode to show me the current version of my project without letting Xcode manage version control.

Normally, I just use Git from the command line. But I decided to give Xcode's gui a whirl, but I've had problems. Somehow, I ended up with two version control folders, each with different branches that weren't exactly the same as my remote repo. I found it frustrating trying to figure out how to get rid of the extra version control folder or even how to get my local branches matched with my remote repo. So I thought whatever I'll just switch back to doing it from the command line. I got rid of my local project. And from Github, I deleted every branch but Master. Then I git cloned my project into a folder locally. I made some new branches via the command line. Added some files to .gitignore. Then launched my project in Xcode. Turned off version control in preferences. But somehow I am only seeing a MUCH older version of my project, much older than the master branch from which I cloned. When I check the folder from vim I see the files as they should be, as they are in the remote repo from which I cloned. From looking at older posts, I see some recommend editing or deleting files. But I don't have any of the files mentioned by other posts.

Someone, please, save me from myself.